# Regex to check if string have only given set of symbols AND defined string somewhere inside

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to write the regexp to check if string contains only given set of characters (`+-*/%|&<>= 1234567890`) and `$val` somewhere inside (possibly multiple times). For example `$val > 100 && $val % 2 === 0` should be accepted, but `10 > 100 && 20 === 30` not.

I wrote regex like this `/^([\+\-\*\/%\&\|<>= \d]*(\$val)+[\+\-\*\/%\&\|<>= \d]*)+$/` but each time i want to add a new character i need to add it in 2 places. Is there a way to write it in more elegant way?

Comment: Build the pattern dynamically using a constructor notation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a lookahead to check the "must have $val" condition first, combined with an alternating consuming pattern to check the second condition (must not have anything *but* $val or legal characters). Note that you can leave many characters  unescaped inside a character class, so we can write it more simply:

```
^(?=.*\$val)(\$val|[-+*\/%|&=<> \d])+$
```

https://regex101.com/r/QZqz3l/2

Answer (score 0):

Does this do what you need?

```
(\$val\s*(\+|-|\*|\/|%|\||&|<|>|=)\s*\d+)\s+(&&\s+|===\s+\d+)
```

NB: I'm using global matching here.

Tested here: https://regex101.com/r/mUhPaK/1

Comment: It only matches $val at the beginning of the string.